# Как в 1С программно узнать номер документа и значение дополнительных сведений?

Tags: 1с

Данный код выводит дополнительные сведения:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ОсновныеИДополнительныеСведения()
    
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   Ссылка
    |ИЗ
    |   Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС
    |ГДЕ
    |   ПодразделениеОрганизации = &ПодразделениеОрганизации";

Запрос.УстановитьПараметр(
    "ПодразделениеОрганизации",
    Справочники.ПодразделенияОрганизаций.НайтиПоНаименованию("Одуванчик")
);

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();

ВыборкаДокументов = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл        
    Док = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
    Для каждого Стр из Док.ДопТаблЧасть Цикл
        
//Код для дополнительного сведения
        
    КонецЦикла;
КонецЦикла; 

КонецПроцедуры
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для примера, в скриншоте есть номер документа `ТД00-000032` и в дополнительном сведении `Наименование`. Как их вывести так, чтобы по номеру документа узнать данные дополнительного сведения?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас типовая конфигурация, то в ней обязательно будет БСП. Для получения доп. реквизитов или сведений лучше использовать её задокументированные методы.

[1С:ИТС - документация БСП](https://its.1c.ru/section/dev/doc_bsp)

В данном случае нужно воспользоваться [методом "ЗначениеСвойства"](https://its.1c.ru/db/bsp314doc#content:5758:hdoc)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам только остается посмотреть, какое имя у вашего доп. сведения. Чтобы передать его параметром в функцию.